# When using IF statement with OR it returns yes no matter what is foo

Tags: php, if-statement

I have:

```
<? if ($foo != 11 || 10) {echo 'Some html code there';} ?>
```

When I run it, if statement returns yes no matter what value is foo.
When I delete " || 10" its working well. Where could be problem?

Comment: I think you mean `($foo != 11 || $foo != 10)` which still makes no sense. But, using `|| 10` means, you are not evaluating `10` against `$foo` you are just asking for `if(10)`

Comment: Yea i mean ($foo != 11 || $foo != 10), but I thought that is right, maybe i forget it, but how I use 2 different numbers to be in one IF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the `|| 10` part.

It's the same as if you said

```
if(10)
```

And 10 is `true`ish. Try this instead

```
if ($foo != 11 || $foo != 10)
```

Comment: If u mean: <? if ($foo != 11 || $foo != 10) {echo 'Some html code there';} ?>
It is not working too, I already tried that. It is returning true even if foo is 11.

Comment: @AlešNezbeda Please do a `var_dump($foo);`

Comment: If I do "($foo == "01" || $foo == "00")", it works. And in my case i can do it that way, but when i try to use !=, it doesn´t work again. But, yea thanks for that. I thought i can use just || 10.

Comment: And var_dump($foo) is 'string(2) "11"'

Answer (score 0):

your code will always get executed no matter what you give as input, because, a number is given suppose 11, for the first condition it'll be false, that is **11 != 11** but, as you're using **11 != 10**, this will evaluate true, thus you'll get the result as true for if block.

For perfect workout, use the negative values first, like what will happen if the values are not those values. or use && operator. 

Hope this should help.